# Problem with JavaScript object manipulation

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript and I'm having some trouble with the `outputallCustomers` function within the `CustomerDB` object. I can output all the customer data (hard coded and inserted into the object in a function not included here) but the call for the `getAddressbyId` function is not working correctly and I can't figure out why.

```
var CustomerDB = {
      customers: [],
      addresses: [],
      stores: [],

    addCustomer: function (customerObj) {
      customerObj.add_date = new Date ();
      this.customers.push(customerObj);
    },

    outputAllCustomers:function () {
        console.log("All Customers\n");
        for (var i=0;i < this.customers.length;i++) {

           console.log("Customer " + this.customers[i].customer_id + ": " + this.customers[i].first_name + " " + this.customers[i].last_name + " (" + this.customers[i].email + ")");
           var customerAddress = this.getAddressById(this.customers[i].address_id);
           console.log("Home Address: " + customerAddress.address + " " + customerAddress.city + " " + customerAddress.province + " " + "." +customerAddress.postal_code);
           break;
        }
      },
    /***********************************
     *           adress methods         *
     * **********************************/
      addAddress : function (addressObj) {
        this.addresses.push(addressObj);
      },
      getAddressById : function (address_id) {
        var result;
        for (var i = 0;i < this.addresses.length;i++) {
          if (this.addresses[i].address_id == address_id) {
            result = this.addresses[i];
            console.log(this.addresses[i].address_id);
          }
          return result;
        }
      },
    }
```

Comment: The `return result;` line in `getAddressById()` needs to be *outside* the `for` loop, not inside.

Comment: ah, Thank you, it is working correctly now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your `return` outside of the `for` loop and use `break` to stop the loop if a match if found.

```
getAddressById : function (address_id) {
  var result;
  for (var i = 0;i < this.addresses.length;i++) {
    if (this.addresses[i].address_id == address_id) {
      result = this.addresses[i];
      console.log(this.addresses[i].address_id);
      break;
    }
  }
  return result;
},
```

Comment: Looping should stop as soon as he gets the correct address.

Comment: Having different return in a function is a realllllly bad practice. I can bring you articles if you're not convinced. Break is the solution.

Comment: I am convinced.

Comment: Hey, I added the break statement within the if condition as you suggested. Thank you guys for the help and info.

Comment: @RobbieD : My pleasure

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
getAddressById : function (address_id) {
        var result;
        for (var i = 0;i < this.addresses.length;i++) {
          if (this.addresses[i].address_id == address_id) {
            result = this.addresses[i];
            console.log(this.addresses[i].address_id);
          }
          return result;
        }

      },
```

With

```
getAddressById : function (address_id) {
        var result = '';
        for (var i = 0;i < this.addresses.length;i++) {
          if (this.addresses[i].address_id == address_id) {
            result = this.addresses[i];
            console.log(this.addresses[i].address_id);
            return result;
          }

        }
       return result;
      },
```

Comment: Outside of the loop, it must return something.

Answer (score 0):

Try next solution

```
var CustomerDB = {
  customers: [],
  addresses: [],
  stores: [],

  addCustomer: function (customerObj) {
    customerObj.add_date = new Date();
    this.customers.push(customerObj);
  },

  outputAllCustomers: function () {
    console.log("All Customers\n");
    for (var i = 0; i < this.customers.length; i++) {

      console.log("Customer " + this.customers[i].customer_id + ": " + this.customers[i].first_name + " " + this.customers[i].last_name + " (" + this.customers[i].email + ")");
      var customerAddress = this.getAddressById(this.customers[i].address_id);
      console.log("Home Address: " + customerAddress.address + " " + customerAddress.city + " " + customerAddress.province + " " + "." + customerAddress.postal_code);
      break;
    }
  },
  /***********************************
   *           adress methods         *
   * **********************************/
  addAddress: function (addressObj) {
    this.addresses.push(addressObj);
  },
  getAddressById: function (address_id) {
    var result;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.addresses.length; i++) {
      if (this.addresses[i].address_id == address_id) {
        result = this.addresses[i];
        console.log(this.addresses[i].address_id);
        return result;
      }
    }
    // Return not found
    return false;
  },
}
```